# Search engine similar to gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a search engine, which will let my users to search my website using syntax similar to this gmail's one.

My website is a map-based directory of restaurants and shops so it would be lovely to make it possible to search it using strings like those:

> Restaurant's name city:Boston diet:vegetarian
>   Restaurant's name country:Belgium tags:fast-food
>   Restaurant's name country:Poland diet:vegan tags:pizza
>   etc...

Have you any idea what can i use to achieve such a functionality? I've browsed all of the solutions from [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_search) but most of them requires to have some kind of special search server set up. I can do that on my VPS but at first i would love to hear your opinion which one is the most powerfull, dev-friendly and which one covers the functionality described above. Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about https://github.com/makandra/dusen gem?

It supports gmail-like token search!

Comment: nice! Exactly what i was looking for :) Too bad it doesn't have a postgres support. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Two other gems I have tried:
https://github.com/bruce/keyword_search (simple token mapper)
https://github.com/wvanbergen/scoped_search (powerful scope, support pg)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use regexp to extract search params from request:

```
search_pairs = params[:search].scan(/([a-zA-Z]+):([a-zA-Z]+)/)
>> [ ['country', 'Poland'], ['diet', 'vegan'] ]
```